# What language is this documentation page coded in?

Tags: ios

I am reading this page :
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html

And I don't see precised what language does it uses for the given code :-/

Is it Java ? C# ? Or other ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: C / Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

This is C, using [Core Foundation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation).

The documentation does indicate this, though it's slightly subtle:

> The main function in the USB Notification Example project (contained in the file main.c) accomplishes the following tasks.
>
> ...
>
> The main function uses I/O Kit functions to set up and modify a matching dictionary and set up notifications, and Core Foundation functions to set up the run loop for receiving the notifications.

The full example code is in [Apple's Open Source site](https://opensource.apple.com/source/IOUSBFamily/IOUSBFamily-630.4.5/Examples/USBNotification%20Example/).